# After installed apache2 and mysql on ubuntu 20.04 i have a "broken install"

Tags: server, apache2, mysql

After  installed apache2 and mysql  on ubuntu 20.04  ,
when i am trying to update :

```
**sudo apt update** or to **upgrade**
```

i have : **dbconfig-mysql : Dépend: default-mysql-client not installed or                           virtual-mysql-client**

it seems to be because of the because of the **ppa ondrej** file in the installation of apache2 and mysql.

Is there something to do,please?

Comment: That package is part of [the universe repo](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/default-mysql-client). Is that particular repo accessible on your system?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply but I had to reinstall the all Ubuntu 20.04